# Curl command not loading contents in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, curl, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin & curl(through cygwin installer) on my Windows7 32bit. Then  opened cygwin terminal and typed `curl --help`. Everything works fine with curl showing its command arguments list.

But `curl http://www.google.com` or any other url takes more time and results

**"curl: (52) Empty reply from server
"**. What is the problem?

Update:Iam behind a proxy server. Any pblm with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your proxy server is the only way to get out at the web, then yes, that's the problem. Curl couldn't care less about what OS you're running under, so won't get for OS-specific proxy settings (ie: Internet Explorer options), so it'll try to do a direct connection. Try adding the `--proxy` option (`curl --help` will give the format).

Comment: Thanks Marc. Its worked. curl --proxy <proxyserverIP>:<PORT> --url http://www.google.com.